# DevOps Pipeline AzureCLI@2 with dynamic azureSubscription

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a DevOps pipeline that gives me this error:

> **There was a resource authorization issue:** "The pipeline is not valid. Job ExecutionTerraform: Step AzureCLI input connectedServiceNameARM references service connection Azure: $(subscriptionName) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

The configuration I am using is looking up the *Subscription* name dynamically.

The step I use for that is:

```yaml
- bash: |
    # pull the subscription data
    # ... read data into local variables

    # set the shared variables
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=subscriptionId]${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=subscriptionName]${SUBSCRIPTION_NAME}"
```

From there I attempt to call the Azure CLI via a template:

```yaml
- template: execution-cli.yml
  parameters:
    azureSubscriptionId: $(subscriptionId)
    azureSubscriptionName: $(subscriptionName)
```

Inside the template my CLI step uses:

```yaml
steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Test CLI
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "ARMTest ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}"
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        az --version
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      useGlobalConfig: true
```

It looks like Pipelines is trying to preemptively check authorization without noticing that there's a variable in there. What am I doing wrong here that is causing Azure to attempt to resolve that at the wrong time?

I do this in other pipelines without issues and I am not sure what is different in this particular instance.

### Update 1: Working Template I have Elsewhere

Full template:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string

jobs:
  - job: AKSCredentials
    displayName: "AKS Credentials Pull"
    steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: AKS Credentials
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: "Azure: testbed-${{ parameters.environment }}"
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: az aks get-credentials -g testbed-${{ parameters.environment }} -n testbed-${{ parameters.environment }}-aks
          addSpnToEnvironment: true
          useGlobalConfig: true
```

Comment: Sorry for stupid question: are you sure you have this working somewhere else?

Comment: I'm sure. I have a task in my update that executes what's there without any issues.

Comment: I'm asking because it clearly the issue descibred on the GitHub. You set your subscription on runtime, and this needs to be know on compilation. So where it happens there is no correct subscription yet. However, if you have this defined in YAML, purely in YAML as variable it would work.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej That's what's confusing me. I know the working template is using it (I have multiple people in there using it right now). But in my new pipeline and the documentation I see - it's not working and shouldn't. But I see it working in another pipeline!

Comment: `${{ parameters.environment }}` this would work if you don't pass as value variable set up on runtime.

Comment: That is defined as an input parameter on the whole script. I guess that what I'll need to do if that's the case.

Comment: I put some more explanation in my reply. The case here if variable is known on compilation or not. In you case not. You must tun pipeline the have variables populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because azure subscription needs to be known at compilation time. You set your variable on run time.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10376) an issue with similar case when it is explained:

> run time variables aren't supported for service connection OR azure subscription. In your code sample, you are referring to AzureSubscription variable which will get initialized at the run time (but not at save time). Your syntax is correct but you need to set AzureSubscription variable as part of variables.

If you define your variables like:

```yaml
variables:
  subscriptionId: someValue
  subscriptionName: someValue
```

and then you will use it

```
- template: execution-cli.yml
  parameters:
    azureSubscriptionId: $(subscriptionId)
    azureSubscriptionName: $(subscriptionName)
```

it should work. But since you set up your variables on runtime it causes your issue.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. I did find a unique way around it. I actually used another pipeline to kick off the primary Pipeline in a programmatic fashion. The "pre-pipeline" looks up all the values and passes them off to the other Pipeline via the API (I already had part of this done for another reason).   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: still the same today in october 22 ?