# Porblem in insert Subscription in AzureCli

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, azure-cli

My team have a task AzureCLI@2:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
displayName: 'KEY VAULT - Get Secrets'
inputs:
  azureSubscription: '${{ variables.azuresubscription }}'
  inlineScript: |
    secrets=$(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $(postDeploy.kvName) --query "[].name" -o tsv)
    for secret in $secrets; do
      pwd=$(az keyvault secret show --name $secret --vault-name $(postDeploy.kvName) -o tsv --query value)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${secret};issecret=true]${pwd}"
    done
  scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
  scriptType: 'bash'
  failOnStandardError: true
```

but '${{ variables.KeyVaultName }}' not working
ocasionally exception: [image]

I try others forms for inject subscription too failure, example inject in env.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, assume you have set up your variable on run time but this needs to be known at compilation time. Run time variables aren't supported for service connection OR azure subscription. You could refer to this ticket: [DevOps Pipeline AzureCLI@2 with dynamic azureSubscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001641/devops-pipeline-azurecli2-with-dynamic-azuresubscription?rq=1) and https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10376 for more details.

As a workaround, you could use [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) in your pipeline.

```
parameters:
  - name: azuresubscription
    type: string
    values:
      - xxxx

jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.azuresubscription }}'
        inlineScript: |
          az keyvault secret show --vault-name xxxx
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        failOnStandardError: true
```